# How Can i Print Array of Images in Winform App in c#

Tags: c#, pdf

hi 
i have a win form app in c# that in this form i have 3 image and a label.
i want to prite these objects into a pdf file.
please help me

Comment: So what have you done so far?

Comment: 'prite'(think you mean 'print') as in storing the images in the pdf. Or do you want the images been print out (out of the printer)

Comment: yes i want print 3 images on a Form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do this:

1. Generate a bitmap from the WinForm control (using [Control.DrawToBitmap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)). You can wrap your images/buttons into the [Panel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.panel.aspx) control and generate the bitmap from that panel.
2. Use any PDF library to generate PDF document based on the bitmap.

For example, that't how to create PDF document from the bitmap using [ABCpdf](http://www.websupergoo.com/abcpdf-1.htm):

```
WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Doc doc = new WebSupergoo.ABCpdf7.Doc();

doc.SetInfo(0, "License", "[your license code || trial license"]);    
doc.Page = doc.AddPage();

doc.AddImageBitmap(myPanel.DrawToBitmap(), false);

doc.PageNumber = 1;
doc.Flatten();

doc.Save("myfile.pdf");
```

-- Pavel

Comment: Also possible you could skip the panel.DrawToBitmap() and add the images directly in to the document. (What I was about to write using TallPDF but not distinctly different enough to warrant a new answer)

Comment: @hometoast: Sure, you can do that. The panel could be used if you want to preserve the layout of child control.