# How to export data in Groupbox into PDF?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I have built a very simple windows form application using C#. But I am stuck here and could not find any help anywhere.

What my simple application does is that it queries out the information in the groupbox which has textboxes labels and buttons. I would like to export or convert the data from in the groupbox into the pdf.

Is there a way to implement that??

Thank you so much in advance~

Answer (score 1):

You may want to have a look at http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/. It's a pretty good framework for what you need.

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

There are so many options, following SO Link provides the solution and it is working it seems

[convert windows form to pdf file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4813341/convert-windows-form-to-pdf-file)

**Other Solution**

1. Use following code to take screenshot
   http://www.developerfusion.com/code/4630/capture-a-screen-shot/
2. Use PDFSharp to save as PDF

Answer (score 0):

there's really a ton of different solutions for this, but you will almost absolutely need a 3rd party library for what you're trying to do.  Google around for a pdf library for c#, as there are several.

EDIT: some possible solutions may be PDFjet, PDFsharp,ABCPDF (do note, if this is part of a commercial application, make sure that the licensing allows use for it)